# Filter multiple conditions from same column

Tags: mysql, sql

My query is, that I want to filter more than one condition from one column same time. ex)

[image]

I want to filter both "Thrissur" and "Ernakulam" from the `Place` column simultaneously. So I tried something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM student
WHERE Place = "Thrissur" AND Place = "Ernakulam";
```

Can you please tell me the correct script?

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
SELECT * from student where Place="Thrissur" OR Place="Ernakulam";
```

alternatively

```
SELECT * from student where Place in ("Thrissur","Ernakulam");
```

The last one is better if you need to add more places, and it can be replaced by subqueries example `SELECT * from student where Place in (Select place from favorites)`

Comment: Why should the last one be better when adding more places? Did you try out? I guess the OR is executed faster.

Comment: I was just thinking for the sake of overview. Particularly if you need many different places, and perhaps (several) other conditions.

Comment: Ok, of course, it's shorter to use IN, that's right.